# How to draw a lines in opengl android

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, vertex-buffer

I've to draw squre using a lines, which will look like as following url.

http://www.thinkingwriting.qmul.ac.uk/wishees/tutorials/square.gif

Could you please tell me how to draw it in android using opengls GL_LINES or GL_LINES_STRIP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly simple, assuming you already have a working OpenGL context:

- Set up an orthogonal projection
- Build a vertex buffer containing the vertices of your square
- When it comes time to render, set line rendering attributes (e.g. `glLineWidth`)
- Render the vertex buffer using `GL_LINE_LOOP` or `GL_LINES` (depending how you set up your vertices)

Take a look at [this introduction to vertex buffers](http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-seven-an-introduction-to-vertex-buffer-objects-vbos/) to get an idea of where to start. There are some much simpler tutorials but this one offers more background than most.

Comment: Can you provide me some example who draws a lines?

Comment: wow, thanks for the link! it's clear and covers pretty much everything I needed to get things running in ES (I have some background in "classic" OpenGL)